# Vaporizing NOx (NO and NO2) with hot metal?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-chemistry

So essentially I'm looking at a product that my intuition tells me is kind of similar to a perpetual motion machine (Impossible).

Catalytic Converters use platinum, rhodium, and palladium to convert Hydrocarbons, NOx, and CO.

NOx turns into Nitrogen and oxygen.

Hydrocarbons turn into Water and carbon dioxide

Carbon monoxide into carbon dioxide.

THIS PRODUCT (see link) claims to "vaporize" "toxic fumes". It doesn't seem to explain what they turn into. just that they go away. (in the report it appears that some of it is turning into oxygen as that number goes up?)

1. Isn't NOx and CO already considered a vapor? how does one further vaporize it?
2. Simply using hot steel to convert gases seems strange but using hot platinum to convert gasses is also pretty strange when you think about it.
3. Is this actually a legitimately effective product?

http://www.impulsengine.com/newproducts/how-it-works_ev_muffler.shtml

http://www.impulsengine.com/newproducts/pdf/Impulse_EV16_Muffler_Emission_Results.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Thin wall channels (this would be the "steel" plates perhaps) in the device are coated with a wash coat of aluminum oxide which is porous and increases the surface area. This allows more reactions to take place since the converters also contain precious metals such as platinum, rhodium, and palladium *e.g. converting NOX into nitrogen and oxygen, hydrocarbons into water and carbon dioxide, and so on.*

These catalytic converters use `oxidation and reduction reactions` to convert the "toxic" fumes—I'm not certain they are stating to work any differently with this regard than other catalytic converters do though. Oxidation is the loss of electrons and reduction is the gaining of electrons at the molecular level. This in addition to the precious metals help promote the transfer of electrons into the conversion of "toxic" fumes to "non-toxic" fumes.

Furthermore, these can also contain oxygen sensors on them measuring and reporting back to the Engine Control Module the oxygen levels in the exhaust. This will help tell other sensors to adjust air-to-fuel ratio helping to keep the catalytic converter running at optimum efficiency.

I would say if this device has a `patent` and has held up to the tests thereof, then it's likely legitimate and accurately effective as advertised by the manufacturer.